# Using Bash/Perl to modify files based on each file's name

Tags: string, perl, bash, oop, substitution

I have a few hundred files which all contain variations of the same class, 'Process'.  My intention is to make each class a derived class of some base clase 'BaseProcess'.
Every file has been manually renames to something like 'Process_XXX' and I am trying to find a way of going through every file and changing every occurrence of, for example:

```
class Process {
    stuff;
}
```

to

```
class Process_XXX : public BaseProcess {
    stuff;
}
```

where XXX is taken from the particular file being changed.  Is this possible using Bash or Perl scripting? Or is it best to proceed manually?
Cheers
Jack

Comment: Are the files actually named `Process_XXX`, or do they also have some extension?

Comment: The names in my question are just examples.  They are actually things like:
CPPProcess2j_ud.cc
which has a header file
CPPProcess2j_ud.h
and here XXX = ud

Comment: That seems like a rather important piece of information you left out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add an answer taking into account the file extensions (adding the changes I suggested to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17788314/1353267) by [fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui)) as well as improvements from [DVK's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119280/dvk) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17788566/1353267):

```
for SUFFIX in cc h java txt; do
    for file in *.$ext; do
        sed -i.bak "s#^\\(\\s*class\\s\\+Process\\)\\(\\s*{\\)#\\1_${file/%.$SUFFIX} : public BaseProcess\2#g" $file
    done
done
```

An example of the pattern is `s#^\(\s*class\s\+Process\)\(\s*{\)#\1_AlertGenerator : public BaseProcess\2#g` with the `XXX` being `AlertGenerator` . I'm using the two `\(...\)` to extract the matches and use them in the replacement pattern as `\1` and `\2` (called `back references` in `info sed`).

Answer (score 1):

If files are in the same dir and have a same pattern name like `file`, this can make it:

```
for file in file*
do
   sed -i.bk "s/Process/Process_$file : public BaseProcess/g" $file
done
```

Note that with `-i.bk` a backup file `$file.bk` will be created.

Tested successfully with three files: file1, file2, file3.

Comment: Hi, using this I get the error
'sed: -i may not be used with stdin'
For every file.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you try just `sed -i "s/process...` (without `sed -i.bk`)? Make sure you make a backup of your files, because they will be replaced with this command.

Comment: use  `"s/Process/Process_${file/%.$SUFFIX} : public BaseProcess/g"` as the parameter to `sed` with the appropriate `SUFFIX=` definition (for eg `SUFFIX=java`) That takes into consideration the filename extensions

Comment: Just for the record, I just posted a new question related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788947/how-to-use-the-name-of-the-file-with-sed-in-a-find-expression

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pi.bak -e \
   's#^\s*class Process {#class Process : public BaseProcess_$ARGV {#g;' \
   Process_XXX
mv *.bak /your/backup/directory
```

This is similar to SED's solution (part of Perl's roots are in sed :) but the benefit is that it can be easily extended if more complicated tasks are needed. E.g. if your files are in various sub-directories, you can use Perl's `File::Find`; or you can rename the files if needed.

Comment: Using this Perl method, does XXX get replaced with whatever values are at the end of the filename?

Comment: You can use `$ARGV` to get the file name.

Comment: @JackMedley - it does now. Sorry missed that part from the Q.

Comment: @DVK - Thanks for your help.  I'm having a little trouble running the script.  I run:
perl -pi.bak -e 's#^\s*class CPPProcess{#class CPPProcess_$ARGV : public CPPProcess {#g;' CPPProcess2j*
In the hopes of changing class definitions such as:
class CPPProcess {... (in file CPPProcess_bc.h)
into:
class CPPProcess_bc : public CPPProcess {...
But none of the files seem to be changed at all?