# How to use the name of the file with sed in a find expression

Tags: bash, sed, find, exec

Trying to answer [Using Bash/Perl to modify files based on each file's name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17788236/1983854) I ended in a point in which I don't know how to use `find` and `sed` all together.

Let's say there is a certain structure of files in which we want to change a line, appending the name of the file.

If it was a normal `for` loop we would do:

```
for file in dir/*
do
   sed -i "s/text/text plus $file/g" $file
done
```

But let's say we want to use `find` to change files from all subdirectories. In this case, I would use...

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i "s/text/text plus {}/g" {} \;
                                              ^
                                   it does not like this part
```

but these `{}` within `sed` are not accepted and I get the error

> sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unknown option to `s'

I found some similar questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4793892/1983854)) but could not generalize it enough to make it understandable for me in this case.

I am sure you guys will come with a great solution for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find` would return *pathnames* (relative or absolute) depending upon the path you specify.

This would conflict with the delimiter you've specified, i.e. `/`.  Change the delimiter for `sed` and you should be good:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i "s|text|text plus {}|g" {} \;
```

EDIT: For removing the leading `./` from the paths, you can try:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '$f={}; f=${f/.\//}; sed -i "s|text|text plus ${f}|g" {}' \;
```

I'm certain that better solutions might exist ...

Comment: Oh that's very clever @devnull . I thought it was a problem with `sed` itself. Thanks for the good explanation. Replacing `{}` with `$(basename {})` I still get the `./`. Any way to delete this part?

Comment: That's it, thanks! As the final solution is pretty similar to the one required in the initial question I came from http://stackoverflow.com/q/17788236/1983854, I would suggest you and Laurent to answer that one as me doing it would be kind of copying your answers.

Answer (score 6):

I really think the issue is that your files name contains a `/` that is why sed believes it start the options strings.

Replace `/` by `@` in you sed command would do the job.

I try that on Linux BASH and it work perfectly

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i -e "s@text@test plus {}@g" {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks @Laurent, I didn't notice that! Your answer was very helpful. I am finally trying to make it work using `basename` as indicated in the comment to devnull's answer. If you see the way to do so it will be very welcome as well :)