# Change extension for every file in dir, except *.txt

Tags: bash, find, cat, mv

I have a directory containing lot of files - `txt` and others.
I want to change extension those others file to `txt`

For now - i use this:

```
find . ! -name '*.txt' -type f -exec ls -f {} + > to_txt.txt
for i in ``cat to_txt.txt``; do 
    mv $i $i.txt && echo $i "File extension have been changed" || echo "Something went wrong"
done;
rm to_txt.txt
```

Script works fine, but i think it is clumsy
Is there any smarter and elegant way to do this?

Comment: In what way(s) do you think this is clumsy, dumb or inelegant?

Comment: i dont know, im quite new in bash stuff, and looking for smooth solutions. As you can see, Fedorqui made it in just one line ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `-exec` to perform the `mv` command:

```
find . ! -name '*.txt' -type f -exec mv {} {}.txt \;
#                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                                    here the magic
```

How does this work?

`find . ! -name '*.txt' -type f` is what you already had: it looks for those files whose name does not end with `.txt`.

Then, the key is the usage of `-exec`: there, we make use of `{}` that carries the value of every file that has been found. Since it acts as a variable, you can use it as so and perform commands. In this case, you want to do `mv $file $file.txt`, so this is what we do: `mv {} {}.txt`. To have it work, we finally have to add the `\;` part.

Comment: Works great ;) aint wont to abuse your kindness, but could you give me a little explanation, what did you do here? Try to understand by `man find`, but with little result

Comment: thak you very much ;) do i understand it correctly - until add `\:` on the end of the line, i can use `{}` to store the file name as variables, and perform another operation?

Comment: @Fangir well not really. You can use it once. If you want to do more things, you need to use `-exec sh -c ' ... '`. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/17789183/